# Unable to delete Application Load Balancer (AWS)

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-elb

I get the following error when I try to delete an ALB:

You cannot delete 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:XXXXX' since it is registered as a target of one or more target groups. To delete this target, you must first deregister it from all target groups.

Then when I try to delete the listeners, I get this error:

Listener port '22' is in use by registered target 'arn:XXXX' and cannot be removed.

Hope you guys could teach me so I can delete this ALB. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the instructions here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-delete.html

These are the steps to delete an Application Load Balancer:

1. If you have a CNAME record for your domain that points to your load balancer, point it to a new location and wait for the DNS change to take effect before deleting your load balancer.
2. Open the Amazon EC2 console at https://console.aws.amazon.com/ec2/
3. On the navigation pane, under LOAD BALANCING, choose Load Balancers.
4. Select the load balancer, and then choose Actions, Delete.
5. When prompted for confirmation, choose Yes, Delete.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFlH1.png)

1. Please follow the path from above image and Turn off the toggle
2. Now you can delete the LB